# Google Polymer: load views from subdirectory

Tags: web-applications, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am currently building a progressive web app with the [Google Polymer Project](https://www.polymer-project.org). But I have problems, loading views from a sub-directory of `/src`. So I have my public folder containing the `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
    <script>
        // Setup Polymer options
        window.Polymer = {
            dom: 'shadow',
            lazyRegister: true
        };

        // Load webcomponentsjs polyfill if browser does not support native Web Components
        (function() {
            'use strict';

            var onload = function() {
                // For native Imports, manually fire WebComponentsReady so user code
                // can use the same code path for native and polyfill'd imports.
                if (!window.HTMLImports) {
                    document.dispatchEvent(
                        new CustomEvent('WebComponentsReady', {bubbles: true})
                    );
                }
            };

            var webComponentsSupported = (
                'registerElement' in document
                && 'import' in document.createElement('link')
                && 'content' in document.createElement('template')
            );

            if (!webComponentsSupported) {
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.async = true;
                script.src = '/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js';
                script.onload = onload;
                document.head.appendChild(script);
            } else {
                onload();
            }
        })();

        // Load pre-caching Service Worker
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
                console.log('Service-Worker registriert!');
            });
        }
    </script>

    <link rel="import" href="/src/app.html">

    ...
</head>
<body>
<my-app></my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

So, this file loads `app.html` from `public/src`:

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      ...
    </style>

    <app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
    <app-route
        route="{{route}}"
        pattern="/:page"
        data="{{routeData}}"
        tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

    <app-drawer-layout fullbleed>
      <!-- Drawer content -->
      <app-drawer>
        <app-toolbar>Menu</app-toolbar>
        <iron-selector selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation">
          <a name="start-view" href="/start">Start</a>
          <a name="login-view" href="/auth/login">Login</a>
        </iron-selector>
      </app-drawer>

      <!-- Main content -->
      <app-header-layout has-scrolling-region>

        <app-header condenses reveals effects="waterfall">
          <app-toolbar>
            <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
            <div main-title>My App</div>
          </app-toolbar>
        </app-header>

        <iron-pages
            selected="[[page]]"
            attr-for-selected="name"
            fallback-selection="view404"
            role="main">
          <start-view name="start"></start-view>
          <login-view name="login"></login-view>
          <view404 name="view404"></view404>
        </iron-pages>
      </app-header-layout>
    </app-drawer-layout>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-app',

      properties: {
        page: {
          type: String,
          reflectToAttribute: true,
          observer: '_pageChanged'
        }
      },

      observers: [
        '_routePageChanged(routeData.page)'
      ],

      _routePageChanged: function(page) {
        this.page = page || 'view1';
      },

      _pageChanged: function(page) {
        // Load page import on demand. Show 404 page if fails
        //var resolvedPageUrl = this.resolveUrl('my-' + page + '.html');
        var resolvedPageUrl = this.resolveUrl(page + '.html');
        this.importHref(resolvedPageUrl, null, this._showPage404, true);
        console.log('Seitenwechsel');
      },

      _showPage404: function() {
        this.page = 'view404';
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

But trying to open `auth/login` returns a 404 because login.html is in `public/src/auth` and not in `public/src`.

What can I do to load views from subdirectories? Defining multiple `<app-route>` doesn't seem to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're hitting 404 for `/auth/login` is because you don't have a page named "auth". Note that the view displayed is independent of the filesystem location of the view's source. Instead, it's dependent on your app's routing.

#### Explanation

In this code:

```
<app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="/:page"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>
```

...your `<app-route>.pattern` is set to `/:page`, which configures the element to parse the first slug in the URL, assigning it to `<app-route>.data.page` (i.e., `routeData.page`). For `/auth/login`, `routeData.page` would be `auth`. The observer (i.e., `_routePageChanged()`) sets `this.page` to `routeData.page`.

In this code:

```
<iron-pages
      selected="[[page]]"
      attr-for-selected="name"
      fallback-selection="view404"
      role="main">
  <start-view name="start"></start-view>
  <login-view name="login"></login-view>
  <view404 name="view404"></view404>
</iron-pages>
```

...the fallback page ("view404") is selected when `page` is not found in the list. Given that the two available pages are named "start" and "login" respectively, a `page` value of "auth" would trigger the fallback page.

#### Possible Solution

Change your login link's `href` from `/auth/login` to `/login`.

```
<a name="login-view" href="/login">Login</a>
```